# multiple rateYo 'load' and 'change'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, rateyo

I am developing web site with ASP.NET CORE and using rateYo script.

How to do best way multiple rateyo load and change event.

My code in below i need better than it cause of it create multiple scripts

```
    <form id="skillRatingForm" onsubmit="return false;">
        <a>Bla bla</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                @{
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.SkillsList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="row form-group col-md-6">
                            <div>
                                <label>@Model.SkillsList[i].Name</label>
                                <div id="rateLanguage_@i"></div>
                                <input id="rateLanguageScore_@i" type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SkillsList[i].Rate" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SkillsList[i].SkillId" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.SkillsList[i].Id" />
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    }

                }
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ResumeId" />
            <div class="buttons pull-right ">
                <input type="submit" class="width-s btn btn-success" onclick="postModal('skillRatingForm', '@Url.Action("RatingSkillPartial", "ResumePartials")', 'skillInfo')" value="Kaydet"/>
                <input type="submit" class="width-c btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" value="İptal"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.SkillsList.Count; i++)
    {
        string modelRating = Model.SkillsList[i].Rate >= 0 ? @Model.SkillsList[i].Rate.ToString("") : "0";
        <text>
            $("#rateLanguage_@i").rateYo({
                rating: @modelRating
            });
            $("#rateLanguageScore_@i").val(@modelRating);
            $("#rateLanguage_@i").rateYo().on("rateyo.change",
                function (e, data) {
                    var rating = data.rating;
                    $("#rateLanguageScore_@i").val(rating);
                });
        </text>
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use ids, use classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create something like this in your page: